# i create plugin for android studio but i get

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, plugins

the plugin contain only one action in toolsmenu or any place in menu  but i always get 
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
 even it's empty action
 android studio 2.3.3 empty project
intellij idea 2017.1.5 i tried both versions  Community and ultimate

> null java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.intellij.ide.SystemHealthMonitor.getActionName(SystemHealthMonitor.java:542)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.SystemHealthMonitor.countActionInvocation(SystemHealthMonitor.java:479)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.fireBeforeActionPerformed(ActionManagerImpl.java:1190)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$2(ActionMenuItem.java:292)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:905)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:284)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$300(TransactionGuardImpl.java:40)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:123)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:109)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:627)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the same question here: [intellij idea create plugin can not use on android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732313/intellij-idea-create-plugin-can-not-use-on-android-studio)

The user Meo points out that you want to use packages

Comment: thank you so much i lost 2 days because just package  ^^ after i post the question i found in related section and it works ^^ 
can i use android studio  Running my plugin when i debug the code instead of intellij idea

Comment: @aymenopa I have never tried, so I couldn't answer that. Is there any reason why you don't want to use IDEA for debugging?

Comment: @cnjash bc the plugin is dedicated for android studio and i have only 4GB of ram i can't open 3 programs with google chrome for document 
 just wasted my time on closing intellij   and wait  android studio   to indexing files and i remove the old version of my plugin and restart android studio and wait android studio  to indexing files again to install the newer version

Comment: @aymenopa Unfortunately I can't help you here. You might want to post a separate question if you keep on running into problems.

Answer (score 1):

I moved action class to package and it worked

Not work:

`<action id="myid" class="MyAction" text="My text"/>`

Work:

`<action id="myid" class="action.MyAction" text="My text"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all, this is so stupid problem...
just need to create package - action
and to put the class to that package...

In addition, there is also a problem with Kotlin DSL, used groovy and it worked !

Worked for me!